# Can onesignal works on ios below ios10?

Tags: ios, ios10, onesignal

can onesignal works on ios below ios10? because I see this warning at link: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup
[image]

Comment: The page only shows that Xcode 8 is required if you wish to get push notifications work on iOS 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. OneSignal works on iOS versions below 10.